# JQuery + CKEditor calling stylesSet.add method

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Getting stumped trying to figure out how to call the stylesSet.add method when using CKEditor's jquery adapter.

Right now my initiation code is:

```
$( '.ckeditor' ).ckeditor( 
    function() { 
        /* callback code */ 
    }, 
    { 
        ... config options
    }
);
```

I've tried adding this to both the config settings and callback with no luck. Not sure how to add this method in

Comment: It's [documented](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles-section-defining-styles). Call `CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add` first and then use `stylesSet` config option in the editor.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that second part to call the newly made styleset. If you can add your comment in as an answer I'll accept it